# For every short exact $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$, the sequence $0\to A\otimes F\to B\otimes F\to C\otimes F\to 0$ is exact

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, tensor-products

[image]

I think it has a lot to do with this theorem:[image]

The only difference being that $F$ in the exercise is a free module, and $M$ in the theorem is simply a module, and that in the theorem the the sequence must split. So I need to prove that the sequence of the exercise also splits, but there's no assumptions over the modules or $f$ or $g$. So what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all sequences split so 7.10 is of no help. Modules for which the functor $M \otimes_R -$ is exact are called **flat**. You can show first of all that $R \otimes_R -$ is exact (i.e. $R$ is a flat $R$-module). Then, using the fact that tensors commute with direct sums, you can show that free modules are flat.

Hint as to why $R$ is flat:

> Note that $R \otimes_R M \cong M$ for all $R$-modules $M$.